# in `require': no such file to load -- active_record (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, require, cloud-foundry

I hope that vcap-service-base of cloudfoundry can visit database of cloud_controller, then I need provisioner.rb in vcap-service-base to require 'active_record'.
So I added "gem "activerecord" "in the Gemfile of vcap-service-base and then ran 'bundle install'.
In the provisioner.rb, I added "require 'active_record'",while starting cloudfoundry, it always threw an error:in `require': no such file to load -- active_record (LoadError), as below:

```
/root/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/vcap-services-base-1077d35ef73b/lib/base/provisioner.rb:9:in `require': no such file to load -- active_record (LoadError)
from /root/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/vcap-services-base-1077d35ef73b/lib/base/provisioner.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /root/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/vcap-services-base-1077d35ef73b/lib/vcap_services_base.rb:4:in `require'
from /root/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/vcap-services-base-1077d35ef73b/lib/vcap_services_base.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /root/cloudfoundry/vcap/bin/../services/mysql/bin/mysql_node:7:in `require'
from /root/cloudfoundry/vcap/bin/../services/mysql/bin/mysql_node:7:in `<main>'
```

According to the error, it was LoadError.
But when I searched the gem "active_record" in /root/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems, it was there exactly.
Now I am confused whether it is the LoadError or I missed something important.
Why in vcap-service-base, can "require 'active_record'" not be found ?

Comment: Have you tried `require'./active_record'`?

Answer (score 0):

When deploying any rails-3 app on cloud foundry, we need to follow the below steps.

1. If any gems are using inside the app, they should do **bundle package** and then again **bundle install**.
2. In `config/environments/production.rb` file, modify the line

   ```
   config.serve_static_assets = false
   ```

   to

   ```
   config.serve_static_assets = true
   ```
3. Pre-Compile the assets using the below command

   ```
   bundle exec rake assets:precompile
   ```
4. Push the app to **vmc** by following command.

   ```
   vmc push --runtime ruby19
   ```